# Using position absolute and sticky

Tags: html, css

So I am making a background for my page, I want the background to always stay on the user's screen so I decided to use position sticky. However, the background needs to be behind of all elements so I need to use position absolute as well, here is my current code:

```css
html{
  user-select: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px -5px 20px black;
  z-index: -9;
  background-color: black;
  background-size: cover;
}

h1#madeby{
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #7289da;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 5px;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #141618;
}

/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #7289da;
}

/* Handle on hover */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #8da5fc;
}
div.home,
img#wallpaper{
  width: 100%;
}

div#wallpaper_container{
  position: sticky;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

img#wallpaper{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}

h2#title{
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #7289da;
}

h2#title strong{
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #f5f5f5;
}

div.song_selector{
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

div.song_selector h1{
  margin: 5px;
}

div.song_selector h1.songs:hover{
  color: #f8e3e3;
  background-color: #7289da80;
}

div.song_selector h1.songs{
  background-color: #7289da2f;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 40px;

  /* border-style: solid; */
  /* border-color: #FFD700; */
  /* border-width: 1.5px; */

  text-align: center;
}

div.song_selector h1.songs strong{
  color: #7289da;
  font-size: 25px
}

a#title{
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #19c1aa;
  font-size: 4vw;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btns strong{
  background-color: #7289da2f;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #7289da;
  font-size: 60px;
}

.btns strong:hover{
  background-color: #7289da80;
  color: #7b96fa;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px black;
}

.btns{
  text-align: center;
}

div.bg_ctn{
  top: 0;
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 0;
}

div.bg_ctn img{
  position: absolute;
  width: 99vw;
  height: 50vw;
  z-index: 0;
  margin-top: -11px;

  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  margin-right:-104px;
}
```

```html
<div class="home">
    <h1 id="madeby">Made by Ivan</h1>
    <h2 id="title">Click To Play</h1>

    <div class="song_selector">
      <h1 class="btns">
        <strong onclick="loop()" id="loopBtn">Loop</strong>
        <strong onclick="pauseplay()" id="pause">Pause</strong>
        <strong onclick="changeSong()" id="changeBtn">Change</strong>
      </h1>

    </div>

    <div class="bg_ctn">
      <img src="https://images3.alphacoders.com/940/thumb-1920-940605.jpg" id="img">
    </div>
  </div>
```

it does not go behind of the elements (the background), instead it stays at the bottom

Answer (score 2):

Try using `position: fixed` instead of sticky, and use `z-index: -1` to make it go behind the text:

```
div.bg_ctn {
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer z-index in CSS. You will need to give z-index to every major part of the page, like header, different  elements, based on what you want on the top. Here is some refrence-

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp